# Refactor method which use django queries to not violate DRY?

Tags: python, django, refactoring, django-queryset, dry

I wrote a to query the model with known lookup types. The flags which denotes what the input type is passed as `kwargs`. The `kwarg` lookup is explained as below along with passed kwargs.

1. A database hash (a random no unique to instances, with `db_hash=True`)
2. Name of the objects ("John" or "Sam" as `name=True`)
3. ID of the object. (obj.ids `124`, or `134` as `id=True`)
4. The instances (objs without any flag)

for example just for the name the method call would look like,

```
self.check_all_routes("Sam", "452", name=True)
```

I want refactor the below method to reduce the mess it is producing while violating DRY.

```
def check_all_routes(self, driver, route, **kwargs):
    _hash = kwargs.get('db_hash')
    _name = kwargs.get('name')
    _id = kwargs.get('id')

    if _hash:
        return self.model.objects.filter(
            driver__db_hash=driver,
            route__db_hash=route
        ).prefetch_related().select_related().values_list('route_number')
    if _name:
        return self.model.objects.filter(
            driver__name=driver,
            route__name=route
        ).prefetch_related().select_related().values_list('route_number')
    if _id:
        return self.model.objects.filter(
            driver_id=driver,
            route_id=route
        ).prefetch_related().select_related().values_list('route_number')

    return self.model.objects.filter(
        driver=driver,
        route=route
    ).prefetch_related().select_related().values_list('route_number')
```

What can be done to make it doesn't violate DRY.

Comment: Can only one of the kwargs be True?

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
def check_all_routes(self, driver, route, **kwargs):
    queries = {
        "db_hash": ['driver__db_hash', 'route__db_hash'],
        "name": ['driver__name', 'route__name'],
        "id": ['driver_id', 'route_id'],
        "default": ['driver', 'route']
    }
    arg = next((k for k, v in kwargs.items() if v), 'default')
    params = queries[arg]
    query = dict(zip(params, [driver, route]))
    return self.model.objects.filter(**query).prefetch_related().select_related().values_list('route_number')
```

It's a bit magic, but the most important part is to build up a dictionary that you then pass to `filter` with the `**` dict expansion syntax.

(Note, I'm not sure your queries are right; these all check that both route and driver match the value, which seems like it won't necessarily be true.)

Comment: It should be 'db_hash' instead of 'hash' in queries keys. I cannot edit your answer since my edit is too small.

Comment: Thanks erhesto, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are brave enough, you can make it a wrapper for filter,

```
def check_all_routes(self, **kwargs):
    return self.model.objects.filter(
        **kwargs
    ).prefetch_related().select_related().values_list('route_number')
```

So instead of passing

```
self.check_all_routes("Sam", "452", name=True)
```

You can do

```
self.check_all_routes(driver__name="Sam", route__name="452")
```

Where you don't need to provide the type. An advantage of this is that you can mix types.

```
self.check_all_routes(driver__name="Sam", route__db_hash="some%hash%string")
```